# Float right makes my columns a mess

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created this html: 
There are two input-fields in a `col-sm-12`:
And in the next column i have a submit button:

```
<div class="row">

   <div class="col-sm-12">       
     <input id="bis" class="form-control input-sm a" type="text" value="18-12-2013" placeholder="Bis" name="bis">
     </input>

     <input id="von" class="form-control input-sm a" type="text" value="02-12-2013" placeholder="Von" name="von">
     </input>
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-12">
     <input class="btn btn-info btn-sm" type="submit" value="Filtern" style="float:right" name="commit">
     </input>
   </div>

</div>
```

And added this extra css to the text-fields:

```
.a {width:100px; float:right}
```

Because i tried to have the input fields next to each other and the submit button in the next colum right below it.

**My problem now is that the submit button now is besides the two input fields! Although i wanted it below!Why? Thanks**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/807/

Comment: input is self-closing, so no need for a </input>. Are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you aren't `clear` after the floated elements.

You have two solutions :

- One add this to your CSS:

  ```
   .col-sm-12 {
      clear:both;
   }
  ```

Here in [this article](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) is all what you need to know about the use of `float`.

- Two use `display:inline-block` instead of `float`:

  ```
   .a {
     display:inline-block;
   }
  ```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/814/**

Answer (score 0):

Use **CSS `clear` property** for this. Refer [**CCS-CLEAR>>**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) for more info.

Here you can try this:

```
.col-sm-12 {
    clear:both;
 }
```